# Connect to SQL Server without ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to connect to SQL Server from Rails app without ActiveRecord adapter.

I followed answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721960/connecting-to-sql-server-with-activerecord). I installed [ruby-odbc gem](http://ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/) and connected to SQL Server from ruby script without any problem.

```
db = DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:ACUMENSERVER', 'login', 'password')
select = db.prepare('SELECT * from customer WHERE id = 1')
select.execute
while rec = select.fetch do
puts rec.to_s
end
db.disconnect
```

But when I am trying to execute this code in Rails controller, error happens:

```
{:forgery_whitelisted?=>"it is just an alias for 'get?' now, update your code"} is not a symbol

/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/deprecated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb    176 in `instance_method'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/deprecated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb    176 in `block in '
```

As far as I know, the `deprecated` gem is  required by `dbi`. When I tried to install the latest version of `deprecated` bundler printed:
`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "deprecated":
dbi depends on deprecated (= 2.0.1)`

What's up? How to connect to SQL Server from Rails 3 without Active Record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I did, after finally finding and reading this: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5250-subclassesdescendants-is-not-a-symbol

1. `gem uninstall deprecated`
2. `gem install rails-dbi`
3. Put this into your gemfile: `gem 'rails-dbi', :require => 'dbi'`
4. `bundle update`
5. It will show that it re-installs deprecated, but it did not seem to cause harm.
6. Your app should run - at least, mine does (but I am using postgres)